# Not able to run any npm command due to following error - Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: npm, nodes, node-modules, npm-install, semantic-versioning

- previously node was working properly.
- After that as i wanted to install express & socket.io.
- it asked for node version update.
- i tried to update node version & i believe i forgot some command to run in updation process.
- now it's giving following error on any npm command. even if i type only npm, that'll give error.

  ```
  m@m-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:/var/www/html/chat$ npm -v
  nternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
      throw err;
      ^

  Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
  ```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @DixitSavaliya - it's not specific package, please read description. i mentioned the process which i followed.

Comment: try to install this package globbaly npm i -g semver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it got solved, i think following process worked.

- deleted npm module from usr folder
- I removed npm module
- cleared the cache
- installed npm

& it worked

The mistake i was doing was not clearing the cache